# Seeds to paper with lore

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I need seeds to change to paper when they come into play. I give a player a stick in gamemode adventure that can only break grass. When they get seeds, I have it change to paper. I want this paper to have a lore on it. How would I do that with my command:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Item,score_Seeds_min=1] {Item:{id:"minecraft:paper"}}
```

Comment: You get answers when you get them.  We frown on bumping questions here; if you're not going to edit your question to clarify, then there's no reason to do so.  To that end, I have removed the parts that weren't relevant to asking your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I put item tags on items inside a chest or your inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/where-do-i-put-item-tags-on-items-inside-a-chest-or-your-inventory)

Answer (score 2):

The `tag` compound of the item format holds any data that is not the root `id`, `Damage`, `Count`, and `Slot` tags. The `display` compound holds the `Lore` list:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Item,score_Seeds_min=1] {Item:{id:"minecraft:paper",tag:{display:{Lore:["Lore line 1","Lore line 2"]}}}}
```